# How to Refresh Whole Graph of Core Plot

Tags: dynamic, graph, core-plot, reloaddata

I try to update Core Plot graph with `[self.hostView.hostGraph reloadData]`, but it did not work properly because after some research, I found (tell me if I am mistaken) that this method update only the charts, not the range or other things.

So, people that configure the graph dynamically based on retrieved data (for example, for plot range, orthogonalCoordinateDecimal, exclusionRange etc.), will have a lot of troubles when the new values change a lot from the previous ones (for example, when we set up the graph in viewDidLoad, and process data in viewDidAppear).

My question is : is there a way to update the whole graph dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, `-reloadData` only updates the plot data. You can call `-scaleToFitPlots:` afterwards to adjust the plot ranges to fit the new plot data.

Consider using `axisConstraints` instead of the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` to position the axes. That way the axes stay in position as the plot ranges change.

Comment: Since I started working on Core Plot 2 months ago, I don't like 'scaleToFitPlots:' because it hides the axes and labels, so I can see only the chart itself. Plot symbols on the limit of the chart are even half hidden. Did I miss something?

Comment: Using constraints will fix the axis positioning issue. Expand the range by a few percent afterwards to show the whole plot symbol. Lots of examples in the *Plot Gallery* app.

Comment: So far, I can use axisConstraints to move the Y axis to the rightmost by setting its upper offset to 0. How can I move the Y axis to the minimum of X values, knowing that X values may change after a refresh? Same question with the moving of X axis.

Comment: Set the lower offset to tie it to the other side instead.

Comment: Yes, but the minimum of X or Y values may change after refresh, so I will need to reset the offset again. Same work as orthogonalCoordinate.

Comment: Constraint offsets are given in pixels from the edge of the plot area. They're independent of the plot range.

Comment: How about 'scaleToFitPlots:' hiding axes? How to solve it? I saw your answer from Dec 2012 suggesting adding a second X axis. So far, have you found something 'more elegant'? Thanks